# Possible to call Apps Script functions from other platforms?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've written some functions in Google's apps script; both return strings of text and require one parameter

Is it possible to call these functions from an entirely different platform?

Specifically, I'm wanting to call function(parameter) when a script I've got set up on an IRC network is triggered.

I was hoping there was some way to do this though HTTP by deploying the code as an app but I'm not sure where to start or if it's even possible

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the ContentService samples [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/content_service).

Comment: Great, that's just what I was looking for. Thank you